# How can I model the Trek Madone 9.0 frame?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I tried modeling a road bike in Blender, unfortunately, I had no luck with it so I decided to ask the blender community.
The bike I intend to model is the Trek Madone 9.0 and really I only need the frame.

At first, I tried tracing a picture so that I could get the basic shape, although It seems I just wasted time.

[image: traced bike frame in blender]

Comment: What exactly you are not able to achieve? What's your workflow?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Try to find a tutorial on modeling something similar or consider practicing 3D modeling with easier shapes first.